# Busca de valores com prioridades

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou querendo fazer uma busca e não estou conseguindo achar a lógica certa para filtrar os resultados que desejo.

Tenho uma tabela com todos os cadastros de vencimento de certos equipamentos. Meu problema está relacionado aqui:

- Os Equipamentos **(1, 22  e 23)** são do mesmo grupo, então caso um deles apareça **OK**, não quero que liste os outros equipamentos do grupo. Caso apareça todos vencido, quero que liste os 3 equipamentos como vencido.
- Já o Equipamento de código igual a **6** se estiver vencido quero que liste, caso esteja OK não precisa listar.

Até o momento fiz a busca dos valores no banco e criei um select para encontrar os dados que preciso, mas não consigo filtrar da forma que relatei.
Segue script:

```
SELECT 
     y.* FROM   
            (SELECT
             e.numcad,
              e.codepi,
              Max(e.datent) AS Entrega,
              Max(e.datent) + p.diaval AS Validade,
              CASE
                WHEN
                  Max(e.datent) + p.diaval <= Getdate() 
                THEN
                  'VENCIDO' 
                ELSE
                  'OK' 
              END
              AS Situacao
            FROM
              r096die e, r096epi p 
            WHERE
              e.numcad = 241 
              AND e.codepi IN (1, 22, 23, 6)
              AND p.codepi = e.codepi 
             GROUP BY
             e.codepi ,  e.numcad , p.diaval

) Y 
GROUP BY  y.numcad, y.codepi, y.entrega, y.validade, y.situacao
```

Print da tabela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*OBS: Tive que postar como imagem pois não consegui add uma tabela dos resultados*

Comment: Eu pensaria em uma FUCTION

Comment: São muitos critérios não relacionados... acho q você deveria fazer `subqueries` para cada critério e juntar tudo no final.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema acima, criando uma tabela `temporária` e depois colocando o `script` em uma `procedure`.

Segue o script:

```
DECLARE @total INT;

SELECT
    E.NUMCAD ,
    E.CODEPI,
    MAX(E.DATENT) AS ENTREGA,
    MAX(E.DATENT) + P.DIAVAL AS VALIDADE,
    CASE
    WHEN
      MAX(E.DATENT) + P.DIAVAL <= GETDATE() 
    THEN
      'VENCIDO' 
    ELSE
      'OK' 
    END
    AS SITUACAO
    INTO #VEN  
FROM
    R096DIE E, 
    R096EPI P 
WHERE E.NUMCAD = 241 
  AND E.CODEPI IN (1, 22, 23, 6)
  AND P.CODEPI = E.CODEPI 
GROUP BY
    E.CODEPI ,  
    E.NUMCAD , 
    P.DIAVAL


SELECT @total = COUNT(*) FROM #VEN WHERE CODEPI IN (1,22,23) AND SITUACAO='VENCIDO';

SELECT * FROM #VEN WHERE (CODEPI = 6 AND SITUACAO = 'VENCIDO') OR (@total = 3 AND CODEPI <> 6 )

DROP TABLE #ven
```